# Hierarchical indexing from a pandas dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, indexing

I have the following **dictionary:**

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}
```

I have binned the **countries** in this dictionary **(keys)** into **continents (values)**.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in ContinentDict.items(): 
    dictionary[value].append(key)
```

This has given me:

```
dictionary
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Asia': ['China', 'Japan', 'India', 'South Korea', 'Iran'], 'North America': ['United States', 'Canada'], 'Europe': ['United Kingdom', 'Russian Federation', 'Germany', 'France', 'Italy', 'Spain'], 'Australia': ['Australia'], 'South America': ['Brazil']})
```

I also have the Pandas series **Reducedset['estimate']:**

```
Country
China                 1.36765e+09
United States         3.17615e+08
Japan                 1.27409e+08
United Kingdom         6.3871e+07
Russian Federation      1.435e+08
Canada                3.52399e+07
Germany               8.03697e+07
India                 1.27673e+09
France                6.38373e+07
South Korea           4.98054e+07
Italy                 5.99083e+07
Spain                 4.64434e+07
Iran                  7.70756e+07
Australia              2.3316e+07
Brazil                2.05915e+08
Name: estimate, dtype: object
```

I would like to create a **hierarchical index** from this dictionary, with the continent as the top of the hierarchy followed by the country.

I have tried the following:

```
totuple = dictionary.items()
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
hierarchy = pop.reindex(index)
```

However, this has **not worked.**

Would anybody be able to give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of tuples and pass to [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
t = [(k, x) for k, v in dictionary.items() for x in v]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(t)
print (index)
MultiIndex([(         'Asia',              'China'),
            (         'Asia',              'Japan'),
            (         'Asia',              'India'),
            (         'Asia',        'South Korea'),
            (         'Asia',               'Iran'),
            ('North America',      'United States'),
            ('North America',             'Canada'),
            (       'Europe',     'United Kingdom'),
            (       'Europe', 'Russian Federation'),
            (       'Europe',            'Germany'),
            (       'Europe',             'France'),
            (       'Europe',              'Italy'),
            (       'Europe',              'Spain'),
            (    'Australia',          'Australia'),
            ('South America',             'Brazil')],
           )
```

And then:

```
Reducedset = Reducedset.reindex(index, level=1)
print (Reducedset)
                                      estimate
Asia          China               1.367650e+09
              Japan               1.274090e+08
              India               1.276730e+09
              South Korea         4.980540e+07
              Iran                7.707560e+07
North America United States       3.176150e+08
              Canada              3.523990e+07
Europe        United Kingdom      6.387100e+07
              Russian Federation  1.435000e+08
              Germany             8.036970e+07
              France              6.383730e+07
              Italy               5.990830e+07
              Spain               4.644340e+07
Australia     Australia           2.331600e+07
South America Brazil              2.059150e+08
```

Another idea is use `map` by original dictionary:

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}


d = {'estimate': {'China': 1367650000.0, 'United States': 317615000.0, 'Japan': 127409000.0, 'United Kingdom': 63871000.0, 'Russian Federation': 143500000.0, 'Canada': 35239900.0, 'Germany': 80369700.0, 'India': 1276730000.0, 'France': 63837300.0, 'South Korea': 49805400.0, 'Italy': 59908300.0, 'Spain': 46443400.0, 'Iran': 77075600.0, 'Australia': 23316000.0, 'Brazil': 205915000.0}}

Reducedset = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

```
idx = Reducedset.index.map(ContinentDict)
Reducedset.index = [idx, Reducedset.index]
Reducedset = Reducedset.sort_index()
print (Reducedset)
                                      estimate
Asia          China               1.367650e+09
              India               1.276730e+09
              Iran                7.707560e+07
              Japan               1.274090e+08
              South Korea         4.980540e+07
Australia     Australia           2.331600e+07
Europe        France              6.383730e+07
              Germany             8.036970e+07
              Italy               5.990830e+07
              Russian Federation  1.435000e+08
              Spain               4.644340e+07
              United Kingdom      6.387100e+07
North America Canada              3.523990e+07
              United States       3.176150e+08
South America Brazil              2.059150e+08
```

Comment: when I try: Reducedset = Reducedset.reindex(index, level=1), this gives me the error: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous. Why is this?

Comment: @Caledonian26 - I think you run first solution and then last paragraph solution, but last solution is alternative by first one. So use first or second solution.

Comment: the last solution does not group the inner index by continent, how can I do that? and when I ran the first solution alone I still got the error message: join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous.

Comment: @Caledonian26 - Then use `df = df.sort_index()` for last solution.

Comment: actually the first solution works when I do: Reducedset = Reducedset.reindex(index)

Comment: @Caledonian26 - For me working nice, edited answer. If not working maybe pandas version problem.

Comment: working fine now: does level 0 mean continents and level 1 means countries?

Comment: @Caledonian26 - exactly.